# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar el contenido de una lista en base a un cuadro convinado en access?

Tags: ms-access

Neccesito que un cuadro de lista en access me muestre cierta información en base a lo que seleccione en un cuadro convinado.
Ambos elementos (lista y cuadro) apuntan a la misma tabla y el cuadro convinado selecciona un criterio de una columna de esa tabla (disponible/no disponible).
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?